# cancel recurring payment of paypal form

Tags: java, php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Creating a paypal form for pyment, In which i am using recurring payment.
Here is that form.

```
    <form name="_xclick" action=${url} method="post"  onsubmit="return validate(this);">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="preetigupta92-facilitator@yamil.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="${chooseService['name']}">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="${amount}">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost:8080/change_service">     
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost:8080/invoice">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost:8080/invoice">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="${amount}">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
    <Input type="submit" class="dsrButton blue"  name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" value="Confirm  change" id="tabOneSubmit"></input>
```

This is working fine, i am getting transition id. I am saving that id in DB. I want to know how i cancel recurring payment like this form or by simple java code.

Comment: This is possible via NVP, But dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Website Payment Standard (Subscribe button - Button Factory) then you won't be able to cancel subscription using any API. you need to cancel it from your PayPal account. Refer to Cancel subscription in [Website Payment Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADF700X44). If you use classic API to create subscription then you can cancel it by using [ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: Yes, I am using payment subscribe button.